# Pass error through ServiceStack UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, error-handling, servicestack

I would like to add error logging to the UncaughtExceptionHandlers of my ServiceStack AppHost configuration while not interfering with the response. The default behavior -- not adding a delegate -- is for ServiceStack to render a screen that displays the ErrorCode, Message, and (in debug mode) StackTrace. However, when I add a delegate to perform some logging, that behavior is overridden and instead I get a blank screen.

I know I have access to the response and can write whatever I want, but **I'd rather just fall back on the default behavior after I've done my logging**. Is this possible?

Reproducing this is simple enough. Just raise an exception during configuration, for example in the GlobalRequestFilters. Comment out the UncaughtExceptionHandlers to see the difference.

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    throw new Exception("oops");
}

UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) =>
{
    //anything that doesn't throw a new exception
}
```

I can throw an exception inside the delegate to get a YSOD instead of a blank screen, but that obviously not the default behavior, and is also written to the event log, which would be redundant in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now fall-through to use the default behavior if the `httpRes` was not closed in the latest [v4.0.40 of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#4040-release-notes) that was just released.

Comment: So glad it wasn't "...just released last week (so you should have updated already)". Thanks!